# How does EF Core instantiate and initialize entities?

Tags: entity-framework-core

How does EF Core instantiate and initialize objects that are retrieved from a database? In the following example, the `Person` class has a default constructor and a parameterized constructor. **Neither of these constructors is called when my program retrieves the `Person` object from the database.**

```cs
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    
    public Person()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Default ctor accessed");
    }
    
    public Person(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Parameterized ctor accessed");
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
    }
}

// Program.cs
// Other code omitted for brevity
var personRead = context.Persons.First(p => p.FirstName.Equals("MyName"));
Console.WriteLine($"Firstname: {personRead.FirstName}");
```

This conflicts with the [microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/constructors):

> When EF Core creates instances of these types, such as for the results of a query, it will first call the default parameterless constructor and then set each property to the value from the database. However, if EF Core finds a parameterized constructor with parameter names and types that match those of mapped properties, then it will instead call the parameterized constructor with values for those properties and will not set each property explicitly

The article was written on 14/10/2020 so it might be out of date. However my question still remains. How does EF core instantiate and initialize these objects? I'm using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore version 6.0.8

Comment: The documentation you quote already told you which constructor is called. What is the question/problem you have?

Comment: If I run my program I would expect the an output saying "Parameterized ctor accessed", as per the documentation. However this does not happen. I wish to know how EF Core can instantiate the objects without calling any of the 2 defined constructors.

Comment: Your second constructor does not have a parameter for the `Id` field, which is most likely a mapped property. Is that on purpose?

Comment: I got "Default ctor accessed"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Neither of these constructors is called when my program retrieves the `Person` object from the database

This can't be true except you have another constructor(s) not shown here.

EF Core definitely uses class constructor for instantiating entities, so the documentation is correct, however it's unclear which one in case there are multiple. All it says is:

> **Note**
>
> Currently, all constructor binding is by convention. Configuration of specific constructors to use is planned for a future release.

The answer is hidden inside the implementation of the [`ConstructorBindingFactory`](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/v6.0.8/src/EFCore/Metadata/Internal/ConstructorBindingFactory.cs) class which is responsible for selecting the constructor to be used, and more specifically the following [comment inside `GetBindings` method](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/v6.0.8/src/EFCore/Metadata/Internal/ConstructorBindingFactory.cs#L112):

> Trying to find the constructor with the most service properties
> followed by the least scalar property parameters

Service properties are explained in [Injecting services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/constructors#injecting-services) section, and scalar property parameters refer to primitive type constructor arguments explained in [Binding to mapped properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/constructors#binding-to-mapped-properties).

In your example, there is no constructor with service type arguments, so the one with **the least** scalar property parameters will be chosen, which in this case is the parameterless constructor (parameters count is 0)

```cs
public Person()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Default ctor accessed");
}
```

Again, if you have other constructors, check if some of them is "better". But as it looks, if you have parameterless constructor (doesn't matter if `public`, `protected`, `internal`, `private` etc.) and no constructors with service type arguments, then EF Core will *always* use the parameterless one.

If you want, you can check the entity instantiation info using the metadata API, e.g.

```cs
var entityType = dbContext.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(Person));
var info = entityType.ConstructorBinding;
```

[`ConstructorBinding` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.ientitytype.constructorbinding?view=efcore-6.0) returns instance of abstract type [`InstantiationBinding` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.instantiationbinding?view=efcore-6.0). [`ParameterBindings` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.instantiationbinding.parameterbindings?view=efcore-6.0) returns information about parameters and corresponding properties, and [`CreateConstructorExpression` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.instantiationbinding.createconstructorexpression?view=efcore-6.0) which

> Creates an expression tree that represents creating an entity instance from the given binding information. For example, this might be a `NewExpression` to call a constructor, or a `MethodCallExpression` to call a factory method.

Currently there are two implementations of aforementioned abstract type - [`ConstructorBinding` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.constructorbinding?view=efcore-6.0) for instantiation using constructor, and  [`FactoryMethodBinding` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.factorymethodbinding?view=efcore-6.0) for instantiation via factory method.

So, currently by convention EF Core uses constructor instantiation, but factory method instantiation might be added in the future (it might even be used currently by proxies extension, but it uses/requires parameterless constructor in the class they are inheriting).

Comment: Thank you for the clear and detailed answer. Using the `ConstructorBinding` property I was able to verify that it is indeed the default, parameterless constructor which is called. However, I still find it peculiar that I do not get "Default ctor accessed" as output. My debugger also does not stop at a breakpoint set in the constructor.